# File upload in ReactNative and CodeIgniter

Tags: react-native, codeigniter

I'm trying to submit form data and upload images from React Native app to CodeIgniter backend server. I'm choosing the images from `react-native-image-crop-picker` and only the data is sent and saved. But not the image is uploaded. I have tried this using Postman and it works perfectly.

I see that `form.append()` has 3 parameters. I checked the Postman request code, and it shows like this

`data.append("attach_report", fileInput.files[0], "...3539240198157045_n.jpg");`

My problem is, what's the datatype of `fileInput.files[0]` in this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found an answer for this. I have seen that the file returns from `react-native-image-crop-picker` is almost a File object. So I just edited the file like below.

```
// image is react-native-image-crop-picker returning file
image.uri = image.path;
image.name = "TEST.jpg";
image.type = image.mime;
image.dateModified = new Date();
```

Then,

```
const f = new FormData();
f.append('attach_report', image, image.uri);
f.append('user_id', 1);
```

Then submit the form. It works in my scenario...