# Uploading Image to server in react native. Getting Error "Network request failed"

Tags: javascript, android, mysql, reactjs, react-native

Calling function :
This is where I am creating a API call.

```
onAddMenuApi(formData) {
    return fetch(UserManagerIns.getUserData('API_URL') + 'menu-item-add', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
      body: formData,
    })
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(response.status);
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(myres => {
        console.log('Item Add API data::::: ' + JSON.stringify(myres));
        return myres;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        return error;
      });
  },
```

Setting Parameters :
This is where I am make a API call after this and set a formData Parameter.

```
let params = {
      title: this.state.title,
      price: this.state.price,
      menu_cat_id: this.state.menu_cat_id,
    };

    let formData = new FormData();
    for (var k in params) {
      formData.append(k, params[k]);
      console.log('My Data :: ' + params[k]);
    }


    formData.append('image_url', {
      uri: this.state.ImageSource,
      name: this.state.filename,
      type: this.state.type,
    });
```

In response I am getting "Network request failed".

I have added in AndroidManifest file the line :   android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

I have added network_security_config.xml as well but it is not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: Check this link for the network issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/57805710/7086832
And https://stackoverflow.com/a/61405318/7086832 for file upload

Answer (score 0):

try this:

headers: {
'Accept': 'application/json',
'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
},

Comment: Already used that. Please read code provided in question.

Comment: Any other solution??